# Density of smooth bi-Lipschitz maps in smooth maps

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, gn.general-topology, gt.geometric-topology, riemannian-geometry, differential-topology

**Setup/Motivation:**
Let $(M,g)$ and $(N,\rho)$ be complete Riemannian manifolds of respective dimensions $m$ and $n$ and suppose that $m\leq n$.  Let $\operatorname{bi-C}^{\infty}(M,N)$ denote the class of bi-Lipschitz smooth maps from $M$ to $N$.  When is $\operatorname{bi-C}^{\infty}(M,N)$ dense in $\operatorname{C}^{\infty}(M,N)$ in the *compact-open topology*?

**Update:** Ben's question affirms a simple "no" for the non-compact case.  But (since I ask for when) if both $M$ and $N$ are compact then can we hope to obtain a positive answer?

Comment: This is also false for compact manifolds, just try to embed projective plane in $S^3$ using such approximation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that neither $M$ nor $N$ are compact and have dimensions both 2 or more.
Take an unbounded real valued function $f$ on $M$ and an unbounded geodesic $\gamma$ on $N$. Map $M$ to $N$ by taking each point $m \in M$ to the point $\gamma(t)$ where $t=f(m)$. This map is smooth but not approximable by any bi-Lipschitz map, since all $C^0$ nearby maps are not onto.

For $M$ and $N$ compact and diffeomorphic, clearly we can't approximate a constant map by a biLipschitz smooth map, i.e. a smooth map, in the compact open topology, as forcing the image of the map to lie in a tiny open set near a point of $N$ forces the map to be trivial on the fundamental class in homology, so not homotopic to a diffeomorphism.

Comment: Is the issue non-compactness; I mean it seems to me that the issue vanishes when both $M$ and $N$ are also assumed to be compact.

Comment: I guess, under the compactness assumption, the problem reduces to asking if all injective $C^{\infty}(M,N)$ functions are dense in $C(M,N)$; which I have no idea if they are.